# HTML - Show an element automatically from a file input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am working in an Angular proyect with [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/)

I will explain my project. I have an Angular component where I list the names of files (input tag). This files were in a database and I get through API and they can be img, videos, code... So far so good.

An example of my front:

[image]

Now I want to do is when user open that component, can watch the image or video automatically. Is there some element in PrimeNG or html that I can use for this?

I know the `<video>` tag or `<img>` tag. But I want a tag that does not depend on whether it is a video, an image or code html.

- Version Angular: 8.2.14
- Version PrimeNG: 8.1.1

Comment: Hey @Alba, you should take a look at this URL it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046879/image-video-preview-in-angular

Comment: you can use regex to get extension of file and then user ngIf for views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the extension of file you can use ngIf directive to show element.

inside your html you can add many tags as you need.

```
<img   *ngIf="getFileExtention()=='jpeg'" src="file_name"  width="500" height="600">
<img   *ngIf="getFileExtention()=='png'" src="file_name"  width="500" height="600">
<img    src="file_name"  width="500" height="600">
<video  *ngIf="getFileExtention()=='mp4' || getFileExtension()=='flv'" width="320" height="240" controls>
  
</video>
```

inside your component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  file_name="abc.png";
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  } 

  getFileExtention():string{
    return this.file_name.split('.').pop();
  }
}
```